# In Azure Logic App, how to break loop inside in case loop condition gets fail for first iteration

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In Azure Logic App, I have one foreach loop (let's say for 4 items)

Within this loop, I am using IF (Condition) Block - TRUE  ELSE Block - FALSE

In case whenever IF (Condition) gets fail, I want to exit the loop.

**Example: 
Loop 1 - TRUE 
Loop 2 - FAIL --  EXIT Loop  -- > No need to iterate for Loop 3 & 4**

As per my requirement, in case of FALSE I need don't have to process the entire Logic App. I just send an email to user.  ***(Technically it is a valid case but functionally it is a custom error for my requirement )***

Comment: Hi Varun05, may I know if this solution can solve your problem ?

Comment: I am using foreach loop. I will modify my logic app next week as currently I can't change the for loop to until due to testing phase. Once i will try i will let you know.

Comment: Hi Varun05, may I know if it works ? If still have any other problem, please feel free to let me know. I will try to help you solve it. By the way, if the solution works fine, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", this can be beneficial to other community members. Thanks~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "[Until](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#until-loop)" action in your logic app. You can create a variable named "status", if success the status is true, if fail the status is false. And put the status into the box of "Until".

You can refer to the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: This does not work. I am unable to break a while loop using this method.

Comment: Adding an `Until` block into a `For each` block does not break the iteration of the `For each`.  It merely creates a second loop, an `Until` loop, inside the original `For each` loop.